# Как сделать ползунок с привязкой к полю с вводом чисел

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: ползунок]

Здравствуйте.

1) Как сделать ползунок с привязкой к полю с вводом чисел. Например ввёл *100* и ползунок тоже сдвинулся на 100. Или сдвинул ползунок и число само ввелось в поле

2) Как под этим ползунком отображать элементы(несколько) в зависимости от числа

Например: Диапазон от 0 - 1000 шаг 100

Если ползунок на 100 Выводим один элемент, в нескольких блоках

Если ползунок на 200 Выводим второй элемент, в нескольких блоках

что-то типо такого <`https://jsfiddle.net/x3aw0v76/1/`> только чтоб над ползунком еще показывалось число, а `item 1` появлялся в нескольких блоках одновременно

Есть ползунок этот. И есть карточки с товарами. В зависимости от числа в ползунке, в карточках появляются элементы. Не в одной карточке. а во всех сразу. Например ставим ползунок на 100 - и в карточках товаров появляется span с надписью СКИДКА 5%... чтото типо такого. Ставим цифру 200 в ползунке - появляется Второй элемент в карточках товаров, например надпись * + подарок к товару*.

Comment: Можно сунуть `<input type="range">`, повесить на него `onchange`, в котором делать нужные манипуляции с достижением определенного значения.

Comment: [Пункт 1](https://jsfiddle.net/2zaj6vxk/). А со вторым пунктом непонятно же ничего. Что значит item1 в нескольких блоках?

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо за 1 пункт. По второму пункту посмотрите пример https://jsfiddle.net/x3aw0v76/1/ там двигаешь ползунок и элементы поочереди появляются. Мне нужно тоже самое, но только чтоб одни и те-же элементы появлялись одновременно в нескольких блоках

Comment: @vp_arth есть ползунок этот. И есть карточки с товарами. В запвисимости от Цифры в ползунке, в карточках появляются элементы. Не в одной карточке. а во всех сразу. Например ставим ползунок на 100 - и в карточках товаров появляется span с надписью СКИДКА 5%... чтото типо такого. Ставим цифру 200 в ползунке - появляется Второй элемент в карточках товаров, например надпись * + подарок к товару*. Надеюсь я понятно обьяснил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отображаемые опции должны существовать в каждом блоке. Их можно разместить статически либо создавать/уничтожать на лету.

В данном примере на каждое изменение значения слайдера, у всех опций проверяется значение `data-from`, и если значение слайдера его превосходит, опция отображается.

```js
const num = document.getElementById('num');
const rng = document.getElementById('range');
const view = document.getElementById('view');
const goods = document.querySelectorAll('.good');
const set = val => {
  num.value = val;
  rng.value = val;
  view.textContent = val;
  [...goods].forEach(good => {
    const options = good.querySelectorAll('.option');
    [...options].forEach(option => {
      option.style.display = val >= +option.dataset.from ? 'block': 'none';
    });
  });
}

rng.addEventListener('input', () => set(rng.value));
num.addEventListener('change', () => set(num.value));
```

```css
#view {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22pt;
}
.ctrl {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.good {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
.good .option {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctrl">
  <span id="view">0</span>
  <input id="num" type=number min="0" max="1000" step="100" value="0">
  <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="1000" step="100" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  <div class="good">
    <span>Good 1</span>
    <p class="option" data-from="100">Option 1</p>
    <p class="option" data-from="300">Option 2</p>
    <p class="option" data-from="700">Option 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="good">
    <span>Good 2</span>
    <p class="option" data-from="100">Option 1</p>
    <p class="option" data-from="300">Option 2</p>
    <p class="option" data-from="700">Option 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="good">
    <span>Good 3</span>
    <p class="option" data-from="100">Option 1</p>
    <p class="option" data-from="200">Option 2</p>
    <p class="option" data-from="1000">Option 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Класс. Огромнейшее спасибо!